# strange jquery .tmpl recursion

Tags: jquery, html, combobox, jquery-templates

I have a real head-scratcher here.  I am using a .tmpl to create the contents of a hierarchical dropdown combobox.  When I use the data and template to just create nested divs the tmpl library works quite nicely.

But when I use a very similar template to create the optgroups and options that go inside the select they end up not nested correctly at all.

The example is here: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dk253/KCYc3/)

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="MySelect">
</div>
<select id="MySelectData" style='display: none;'>
</select>
<br />
<div id="MyDiv">
</div>
<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{if children}}
    <optgroup label='${data}'>
        {{tmpl(children) "#MyTemplate"}}
    </optgroup> 
    {{else}}
    <option label='${data}'>
        ${data}
    </option>
    {{/if}}
</script>
<script id="MyDump" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{if children}}
    <div style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
        ${data}
        {{tmpl(children) "#MyDump"}}
    </div> 
    {{else}}
    <div style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
        ${data}
    </div>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

And the jQuery (including data):

```
var data = [{
    "data": "Corporate",
    "children": [{
        "data": "Division A",
        "children": [{
            "data": "Department AA",
            "children": [{
                "data": "Product AA1"},
            {
                "data": "Product AA2"}]},
        {
            "data": "Department AB",
            "children": [{
                "data": "Product AB1"}]},
        {
            "data": "Department AC",
            "children": [{
                "data": "Product AC1"},
            {
                "data": "Product AC2"},
            {
                "data": "Product AC3"},
            {
                "data": "Product AC4"}]}]},
    {
        "data": "Division B",
        "children": [{
            "data": "Department BA",
            "children": [{
                "data": "Product BA2"},
            {
                "data": "Product BA`1"}]},
        {
            "data": "Department BB",
            "children": [{
                "data": "Product BB1"},
            {
                "data": "Product BB2"},
            {
                "data": "Product BB3"}]}]},
    {
        "data": "Division C",
        "children": [{
            "data": "Department CA",
            "children": [{
                "data": "Product CA1"}]}]}]}];
$("#MyTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo('#MySelectData');
$('#MySelect').combo({
    selectId: 'MySelectData',
    editable: false,
    width: 150
});
$("#MyDump").tmpl(data).appendTo('#MyDiv');
```

And these plugins:

- https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.js
- http://imagestore2.boomerang.com/img/resources/js/ccombo/2.0.0/jquery.combo.js

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to nest `<optgroup>` elements but that is invalid HTML. [HTML-5 has this to say about `<optgroup>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-optgroup-element):

> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>   As a child of a `select` element.
>   **Content model:**
>   Zero or more `option` elements.

And [HTML-4 has this to say](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTGROUP):

> In HTML 4, all `OPTGROUP` elements must be specified directly within a `SELECT` element (i.e., groups may not be nested).

So you're giving the browser invalid HTML and the browser is trying to correct it by unnesting the invalidly nested `<optgroup>` elements. Once the browser has finished correcting your HTML your nesting is gone and get the odd behavior that you're seeing.

How do you solve this? You could use nested `<ul>`s (inside a hidden `<div>`) for the JavaScript version and a completely different `<select>` without nested `<optgroup>` elements for the non-JavaScript version. You could also try playing tricks with an extra depth attribute so that your JavaScript could rebuild the nesting (I've done this before, doesn't mean that it is a good idea just that it is possible).